# Having trouble understanding why we use and how to use two structs for a binary search tree

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-search-tree, abstract-data-type

I'm working on a program that involves using a Binary search tree and I am trying to initialize the BST. But I'm having a hard time understanding why we use two structures, and why I am getting "request for member left in something not a structure or union"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ADD_LENGTH 30



typedef struct treeType{
    int listingId, price, propertySize;
    int numOfBeds, yearBult;
    char agent[20];
    char address[ADD_LENGTH];
    struct treeType *left;
    struct treeType *right;

}bNode;

typedef struct treeFrame{
    bNode *node;

}bTree;
void init(bTree **tree);


int main(void)
{
    bTree *tree;
    init(&tree);

    return 0;
}

void init(bTree **tree){
    tree = NULL;
    tree->left = NULL;
    tree->node->right = NULL;


}
```

Comment: `void init(bTree **tree){
 *tree = malloc(sizeof(**tree));
 (*tree)->node = malloc(sizeof(bNode));
 (*tree)->node->left = NULL;
 (*tree)->node->right = NULL;
}`

Comment: In `tree->left = NULL;` you're missing `node->`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm having a hard time understanding why we use two structures

You are dealing with two abstractions -- tree and nodes of a tree. It makes perfect sense to use two `struct`s, one for each abstraction.

Your posted `struct` for the tree, `bTree`, has only one member, the root node. You can potentially add other members to it -- the number of nodes in the tree, the maximum of depth of the leaf nodes in tree, etc. Granted that these can be computed but it might be useful to have them as member variables and update them when you modify the tree to make them available without the paying the cost of traversing the tree.

The main thing to remember is that a tree and the nodes of a tree are two different abstractions. They *should* be defined using two different `struct`s. Each can be extended/updated independently depending on the needs of the application.

> why I am getting "request for member left in something not a structure or union"

Code in the function `init` is wrong for several reasons.

1. You have not allocated any memory for the "tree".
2. You are using the variable `tree` in correctly. In the function, `tree` of type `bTree**`. It is a pointer to a pointer to a `bTree`.
3. `bTree` does not have a member called `left`. Hence your attempt to use `tree->left = NULL;` is not correct.

What you need is something like:

```
void init(bTree **tree) 
{
   // Allocate memory for the tree.
   *tree = malloc(sizeof(bTree));

   // Make the root node NULL to indicate it is an empty tree.
   (*tree)->node = NULL;
}
```

Comment: By abstraction, what does that mean?
Also should i set the *tree to NULL if I wanted to check if the root is NULL should setting the root be included in the init function?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29 for the meaning abstraction. See the updated `init` function.